# Angular issue with: ng-html-bind='ans'

Tags: angularjs

`<p ng-bind-html='ans'> {{ans}}  </p>` prints as:-

`<p> hi </p>` instead of

hi

where `$scope.ans = '<p> hi </p>'`

I am using angularjs version 1.2.1

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/iAE2CLqwR67MwrIv455m)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you just use ngBindHtml, however you need to include angular-sanitize[.min].js, and add "ngSanitize" to your module.

[ngBindHtml Documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angBindHtml)

Answer (score 0):

You set $scope.ans.body to a string containing the paragraph tags... If you just want it to output 'hi' set the expression that is being evaluated to the string 'hi':

```
$scope.ans.body = 'hi'
```

Also why do you use the ng-html-bind ?